# Android Tweetdeck-like UI

Tags: android, user-interface, workspace

I'm getting started with Android development, and I would like to have an interface similar to that of tweetdeck: there are several workspaces (activities) that are laid out left to right, and the user can switch between them with a horizontal gesture. The same way the Android desktops are switched.

In tweetdeck there are also dots in the titlebar, that indicate on which side and how many workspaces there are.

Is it a standard Android interface, or something custom built? How do I do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you go about this is going to be partially dependent on the content you want to present. If there are going to be many heavyweight pages you'll want to look into doing something like a custom [`AdapterView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html). If there are only a few fixed pages such as in the stock home screen you can treat it like a scrollable view with some custom logic to handle snapping to pages.

Here's a link to the custom view that implements this in the stock Android launcher. The bits you're interested in will mostly be in `onTouchEvent`, `onInterceptTouchEvent`, and `computeScroll`.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/master/src/com/android/launcher2/Workspace.java

Comment: A new widget ViewPager has been added to the Android support library that can implement this kind of interaction. It is compatible with API level 4 and up. See http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ViewFlipper: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

Comment: Any time this comes up someone mentions ViewFlipper. It doesn't do this sort of workspace panning. At best you'll get a delayed animation after the fact in response to a fling.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to studying the actual Android code (referenced in another answer), some folks have extracted and isolated the workspace (Launcher2) code into a re-usable view group. You can find the work in github here https://github.com/olibye/AndroViews